# GRUB menu is not shown after Xubuntu 18.04 update

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, updates, laptop, thinkpad

I'm on a dual-boot setup (Windows 10 + Xubuntu 18.04). It was working fine until I left Xubuntu without updates for 2 months.
Then, after update, the grub menu for selecting OS is no longer shown. Also, the boot process is taking longer now. Sometimes even it hangs on "Lenovno" logo after POST.
Then I did a `sudo update_grub`:

```
[sudo] password for user:
Sourcing file `/etc/default/grub'
Generating grub configuration file ...
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
Found linux image: /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic
Found initrd image: /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic
Found Windows Boot Manager on /dev/sda2@/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
Adding boot menu entry for EFI firmware configuration
done
```

Which didn't fix the issue. Here is my `/etc/default/grub`:

```
# If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
# /boot/grub/grub.cfg.
# For full documentation of the options in this file, see:
#   info -f grub -n 'Simple configuration'

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

# Uncomment to enable BadRAM filtering, modify to suit your needs
# This works with Linux (no patch required) and with any kernel that obtains
# the memory map information from GRUB (GNU Mach, kernel of FreeBSD ...)
#GRUB_BADRAM="0x01234567,0xfefefefe,0x89abcdef,0xefefefef"

# Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
#GRUB_TERMINAL=console

# The resolution used on graphical terminal
# note that you can use only modes which your graphic card supports via VBE
# you can see them in real GRUB with the command `vbeinfo'
#GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600
# Added two lines to decrease grub resolution (hence larger font size)
#GRUB_GFXMODE=800x600x32
#GRUB_GFXPAYLOAD_LINUX=keep

# Uncomment if you don't want GRUB to pass "root=UUID=xxx" parameter to Linux
#GRUB_DISABLE_LINUX_UUID=true

# Uncomment to disable generation of recovery mode menu entries
#GRUB_DISABLE_RECOVERY="true"

# Uncomment to get a beep at grub start
#GRUB_INIT_TUNE="480 440 1"
```

Note that I've updated Xubuntu **not Windows 10** so I don't think windows has messed up with it.

**update**
`/boot/grub/grub.cfg`

```
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt6'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=en_US
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=hidden
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback hidden-timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  elif sleep --interruptible 10 ; then
    set timeout=0
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=1
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt6'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
    fi
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic root=UUID=41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
}
submenu 'Advanced options for Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-74-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-74-generic-advanced-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-74-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic root=UUID=41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-74-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-74-generic-recovery-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-74-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-74-generic root=UUID=41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-74-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-72-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-72-generic-advanced-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-72-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic root=UUID=41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.4.0-72-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.4.0-72-generic-recovery-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.4.0-72-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.4.0-72-generic root=UUID=41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.4.0-72-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-62-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-62-generic-advanced-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-62-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic root=UUID=41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 5.3.0-62-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-5.3.0-62-generic-recovery-41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt6'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt6 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt6 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt6  41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25
        fi
        echo    'Loading Linux 5.3.0-62-generic ...'
            linux   /boot/vmlinuz-5.3.0-62-generic root=UUID=41029103-4149-4d29-8b35-805155d25e25 ro recovery nomodeset dis_ucode_ldr 
        echo    'Loading initial ramdisk ...'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-5.3.0-62-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (on /dev/sda2)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-C21E-27D0' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt2'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt2 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt2 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt2  C21E-27D0
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root C21E-27D0
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
```

`sudo parted -l`

```
Model: ATA TOSHIBA MQ01ABD0 (scsi)
Disk /dev/sda: 500GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/4096B
Partition Table: gpt
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End    Size    File system  Name                          Flags
 1      1049kB  556MB  555MB   ntfs         Basic data partition          hidden, diag
 2      556MB   661MB  105MB   fat32        EFI system partition          boot, esp
 3      661MB   677MB  16.8MB               Microsoft reserved partition  msftres
 4      677MB   285GB  285GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 5      285GB   393GB  107GB   ntfs         Basic data partition          msftdata
 6      393GB   500GB  107GB   ext4
```

Comment: Are you aware that *flavors* of Ubuntu only come with three years of supported life (five years applies to Ubuntu Desktop, Ubuntu Server but not flavors), so you're asking about a release that in April reached it's EOL.  (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2020/08/14/ubuntu-18-04-5-lts-released/ or a UWN - https://wiki.ubuntu.com/UbuntuWeeklyNewsletter/Issue681#Lubuntu_18.04_LTS_End_of_Life_and_Current_Support_Statuses highlights the EOL notices for Lubuntu/Ubuntu-MATE/Kubuntu/Ubuntu-Budgie; Xubuntu didn't announce EOL but refer https://xubuntu.org/release/18-04/ you'll see it's 29 April)

Comment: Check your boot process in your BIOS. Is your PC really booting the Xubuntu boot loader or is it the default windows version.

Comment: @guiverc yeah I plan to update but I've postponed it.

Comment: @rm- Can a ubuntu update change BIOS settings? I literally didn't do anything except `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade`

Comment: Need to see your /boot/grub/grub.cfg file. Not all of it, just all of the first menu entry (for     Xubunti) down to its closing brace. Also need to see output of `sudo parted -l`

Comment: @PaulBenson I've updated the post with your required info

Comment: The only thing I can suggest that sometimes causes an issue is the 'GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden' which should be changed to `=menu`. Else I can't see any other issue with your grub file. Change it in `/etc/default/grub` and save, then `sudo update-grub` and  reboot to see if it makes any difference. Try this first.

Comment: @Zeta.Investigator. Yes there are BIOS updates available via Linux. I was more thinking on a Windows BIOS update who might have messed things up for you.